# Google Calendar Events Watch 400 pushNotSupportedForRequestedResource

Tags: google-calendar-api

I am trying to subscribe to all user's calendars, but some calendars do not support this functionality.

Request:

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/{calendarId}/events/watch
```

Response:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "calendar",
    "reason": "pushNotSupportedForRequestedResource",
    "message": "Push notifications are not supported by this resource."
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Push notifications are not supported by this resource."
 }
}
```

How I can find out whether the current calendar support "watch"?
Does it corresponding to "accessRole" from [calendar#calendarListEntry.accessRole](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList)

Comment: Do you have permission to view the events of those Calendars? In other words, are those calendars shared with you?

Comment: Yes I have permission to read such calendars, and look like that they are shared with user. 

Example of ids: en.usa#holiday@group.v.calendar.google.com, p#weather@group.v.calendar.google.com or fifa%7e_wcup_7625_%45ngland#sports@group.v.calendar.google.com

Comment: As [notifications](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37242?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&hl=en) can be disabled, I guess those calendars doesn't have them enabled, maybe for all the calendar or some specific events.

Comment: I too have the same question. Is there any way we can find out a given calendar will be allowed for webhook(watch or channel) or not?

Comment: @Vladimir did you find the answer to it?

Comment: @itsoft3g did you find the answer to it?

Comment: @VikashRathee Not yet